# Yii Captcha image was not displayed on my web hosting

Tags: php, yii, captcha

i have a Yii Web project in localhost. The site works perfectly in localhost but in the web hosting the yii captcha image was not displayed.

My SiteController :

```
public function accessRules()
    {
        return array(
            array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
                // need to allow captcha in order to view it.
                'actions'=>array('create','view','index','captcha'),
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
            );
    }
public function actions(){
        return array(
        // captcha action renders the CAPTCHA image displayed on the contact page
            'captcha'=>array(
            'class'=>'CCaptchaAction',
            'backColor'=>0xFFFFFF,
            ),
}
```

My ContactForm Model:

```
public $verifyCode;
public function rules()
    {
        return array(
            // name, email, subject and body are required
            array('name, email, subject, body', 'required'),
            // email has to be a valid email address
            array('email', 'email'),
            // verifyCode needs to be entered correctly
            array('verifyCode', 'captcha', 'allowEmpty' => !extension_loaded('gd')),
            );
    }
```

My contact view:

```
  <?php if(extension_loaded('gd')): ?>
        <div class="span4">
            <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'verifyCode'); ?>
            <?php echo $form->textField($model,'verifyCode'); ?>
            <div>
                <?php $this->widget('CCaptcha'); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="hint">Please enter the letters as they are shown in the image above.
            <br/>Letters are not case-sensitive.</div>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

My hosting:
Library GD

```
GD Support  enabled
GD Version  bundled (2.1.0 compatible)
FreeType Support    enabled
FreeType Linkage    with freetype
FreeType Version    2.4.2
T1Lib Support   enabled
GIF Read Support    enabled
GIF Create Support  enabled
JPEG Support    enabled
libJPEG Version 6b
PNG Support enabled
libPNG Version  1.2.44
WBMP Support    enabled
XPM Support enabled
libXpm Version  30411
XBM Support enabled
Directive   Local Value Master Value
gd.jpeg_ignore_warning  0   0
```

My localhost server:

```
gd
GD Support  enabled
GD Version  bundled (2.0.34 compatible)
FreeType Support    enabled
FreeType Linkage    with freetype
FreeType Version    2.4.11
T1Lib Support   enabled
GIF Read Support    enabled
GIF Create Support  enabled
JPEG Support    enabled
libJPEG Version 9
PNG Support enabled
libPNG Version  1.5.14
WBMP Support    enabled
XPM Support enabled
libXpm Version  30411
XBM Support enabled

Directive   Local Value Master Value
gd.jpeg_ignore_warning  0   0
```

My .php files are in UTF8 wihout BLOM
Do not understand why it does not work :(

Comment: imagemagick installed in your server ?

Comment: Hi ramamoorthy, my hosting dindt have installed imagemagick library.

Comment: ok try by installing imagemagick.  what OS your server is ?

Comment: My server is provided by OVH. The os is linux. I will open a ticket for install the imagemagick library. Thanks for u help

Comment: My Web hosting doesnt allow me install imagemagick library : \. Maybe i should try use other extension for generate the captcha